# Chevychev's Inequality Tax

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

A tax agency processes $2,000$ tax returns and rounds individual tax refunds to the
nearest integer. (Refunds of the form $n+0.5$ with $n ∈ Z$ are rounded to $n+1$.) For
simplicity, assume that the rounding errors in these tax returns are stochastically
independent and follow the uniform distribution on the interval $[−0.5,0.5]$. Let S be
the agency’s total loss or profit due to the rounding process.

Show that $P(S \geq 50) \leq \frac{1}{15}$

I think I solved it.

Let $S=S_1 + S_2 +.... +S_{2000}$.

We have $S_i$ ~ unif[$-0.5,0.5$] for each individual tax return up to the $2000$th one. I worked out $E[S_i]=0$ and Var$(S_i)=\frac{1}{12}$.So Var($S)= \frac{2000}{12}$ and E[$S]=0$.

By Chebychev's inequality, $P(S \geq 50) = P(S - 0 \geq 50) \leq P(|S - 0| \geq 50) \leq \frac{\frac{2000}{12}}{50^2} = \frac{1}{15} $

Comment: That looks correct.